# ionic 2 when slide swipe left or right need to pause or destroy previous event

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

In ionic 2 m using ion-slide tag in html inside ion-slide  m using video, audio and image tags.So problem getting is when i play video and swipe next that video is not getting pause.Can someone suggest solution how can i control video and audio on view change.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to output event of ion-slides component and do logic to stop the playing video/audio. You can use ionSlideDidChange event or any other suitable events, you can check this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/#output-events) to find the list of events available. So the code will look something like below

> In HTML

```
<ion-slides (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()">
```

> In controller

```
slideChanged() {
    pauseAudioVideo()// Logic to stop the running video/audio
  }
```

Comment: pause and play is not in our control.So can't implement pause on slidechange